# Is there any reason to expect that a USB floppy drive marketed for Windows will fail to work with a Mac?

Tags: windows, usb, hardware, driver, compatibility

Someone else [asks about using a USB floppy drive on a modern Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/312502/3553), and the answer is that they "still work".  This implies that the answerer is talking about a USB that previously worked on a Mac, but that doesn't clarify whether a USB floppy drive marketed as a Windows product will also work for Macs.

Since that question is unclear, I'll make it very explicit:  *Can we assume a USB floppy drive made for Windows will necessarily also work on a Mac?*

To make the difference between my question and the other question absolutely clear, I'm not talking about whether a new version of macOS will continue to support hardware supported by an old version of macOS, in this case a USB floppy drive.  I'm asking whether there is any reason to expect that a USB floppy drive marketed for Windows will fail to work with a Mac.

Comment: Define modern Mac. I suppose if you installed Windows on an Intel Mac you might be able to use the drive. You might consider including in your question the versions Windows supported by the drive, the types of USB supported by the drive, the model of the Mac, the version of macOS installed and how the floppies are formatted.

Comment: The other question _may (or may not)_ have been meant to imply that any USB floppy drive will work with a Mac simply because it is USB.  If you need a definition of "Modern Mac" then use this: hardware from 2015 or later running macOS 10.15 or later.  (NOT Windows!)

Comment: The other question was posted when all modern Macs used Intel processors. Currently, the most modern Macs use Apple Silicon processors. If your Mac is Intel, then you could install Windows 10 or Windows 10 in a virtual machine, then use or share the drive from Windows.

Comment: It would make more sense to just use a Windows machine.  I'm looking for a way to avoid all that pain. Installing Windows on my Mac hardware is far more pain than just digging up an old Windows machine.  But doing anything on Windows is a pain.  I'm trying to find an alternative.

Comment: At some point you will have to try it for yourself. Here is a recent example of success https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/floppy-disk-readable-drive-for-macs.2339688/. There are really 2 questions. 1) Drive: I think you can assume that most USB floppy drives will work with Mac. 2) Format: If the floppies are in one of the FAT formats, will be easily readable.

Comment: Are you asking whether a USB floppy drive as such will work on a Mac or whether a specific floppy disk can be read afterwards? Also, both seems to be märtet by the question you link to, not sure what additional information you seek.

Comment: @nohillside:  I'm asking whether a USB floppy drive will work on a Mac.  The other question only clearly answers that if it worked before then it should still work.

Comment: The answer there says "The short answer is yes, external USB floppy drives will still work with macOS.", which IMHO answers the question "whether a USB floppy drive will work on a Mac". Also, I did some some [basic research](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=usb+floppy+drive+mac) and found several articles/product descriptions implying the same.

Comment: @Gilby: the file format of the disk is not relevant to the question.  I'm asking about the drive, not the removable disk.

Comment: @nohillside: NOPE, the word "STILL" implies that a drive that previously worked will continue to work.  It says NOTHING about whether a drive designed for Windows will work on Mac.  Did you actually read my question?  I already explained this.

Comment: „Still work on macOS“, as they did on the computers mentioned in the question. Which basically is the same answer as you would get again here. Whether a specific product will work is hard to know without knowing the product, but there are USB floppy drives which mention macOS.

Comment: "Whether a specific product will work is hard to know without knowing the product".  Your words imply that there IS a difference between a USB Floppy Drive made for Mac and one made for Windows.  Do you actually know that?  Or are you just making an assumption?

Comment: I have the answer for this question - if someone could reopen it, that would be great.

Comment: USB floppy drives are generally made to work as "mass storage device" class devices (i.e. I have tried many different products, and they all works this way). This is supported on macOS - and it works on all Macs, no matter if it is Intel or Apple Silicon. It doesn't make any difference at all. You can use them with Mac software, or you can use them from Windows - BootCamp or virtualized Windows - doesn't make a difference at all. Also there's no difference at all between USB floppy drives for Mac and for Windows as such. They work the same way for both platforms.

Comment: The only thing you need to keep in mind is the type of floppy disk you want to read - that has to match the drive's capabilities. I.e. it hasn't got anything to do with whether you're using the USB floppy drive on Windows or Macintosh, but you have to ensure that your drive actually supports the type of floppy you want to read. I.e. it's not given that a drive that supports reading from IBM-compatible 1.44 MB 3.5" disks also supports reading from Mac formatted 400 kB 3.5" disks.

Comment: @jksoegaard excellent answer!  Thank you!  If we limit our discussion to 1.44 MB floppies, I would guess that "type of floppy" is distinguished only by the way the floppy was formatted, right?  (I don't think I have any of the 400kb or 800kb diskettes.)

Comment: When I wrote type of floppy, I meant actual hardware differences in how they are read. If you just have standard IBM compatible 1.44 MB floppies then you can format them any way you like. That has nothing to do with the drive or the USB connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB floppy drives are generally made to work as "mass storage device" class devices (I have tried many different products, and they all work this way).

This is supported on macOS - and it works on all Macs, no matter if it is Intel or Apple Silicon. It doesn't make any difference at all.

There's no difference at all between USB floppy drives for Mac and for Windows as such. They work the same way for both platforms.

You can use the floppy drive with macOS software, or you can use it from Windows - BootCamp or virtualized Windows - doesn't make a difference at all.

The only thing you need to keep in mind is the type of floppy disk you want to read - that has to match the drive's capabilities. I.e. it hasn't got anything to do with whether you're using the USB floppy drive on Windows or Macintosh, but you have to ensure that your drive actually supports the type of floppy you want to read. I.e. it's not given that a drive that supports reading from IBM-compatible 1.44 MB 3.5" disks also supports reading from Mac formatted 400 kB 3.5" disks.